# Error:"export 'FirebaseNameOrConfigToken' (imported as 'i57') was not found in '@angular/fire'

Tags: angular, firebase, mean-stack, angularfire2, angular9

Getteing this error when i run my program using this command -> ng s

> "export 'FirebaseNameOrConfigToken' (imported as 'i57') was not found
> in '@angular/fire'
> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 126:16579-16608
> "export 'FirebaseNameOrConfigToken' (imported as 'i57') was not found in '@angular/fire'
> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 126:6876-6900
> "export 'FirebaseOptionsToken' (imported as 'i57') was not found in '@angular/fire'
> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 126:7016-7040
> "export 'FirebaseOptionsToken' (imported as 'i57') was not found in '@angular/fire'
> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 126:16194-16218
> "export 'FirebaseOptionsToken' (imported as 'i57') was not found in '@angular/fire'
> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 126:7082-7105
> "export 'RealtimeDatabaseURL' (imported as 'i57') was not found in '@angular/fire'
> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 126:6850-6873
> "export '_firebaseAppFactory' (imported as 'i57') was not found in '@angular/fire'
>
> Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open
> your browser on http://localhost:4200/

here my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.9",
    "al-shah": "^1.9.7",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "firebase": "^7.16.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.4.3",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
```

and app.module.ts:

```
import { AngularFireModule } from "angularfire2";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./modules/app-routing.module";
import { firebaseConfig } from "./firebase/firebase-config";
imports:[
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
  ],
```

here moto.component.ts

```
export class MotoComponent {
  mobParts: any[];
  constructor(private angularFireDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {
    angularFireDatabase
      .list("/motoData")
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe((mobParts) => {
        this.mobParts = mobParts;
        console.log(this.mobParts);
      });
  }
}
```

I have firebase/firebase.json

```
export var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCx2EGL7OKRwWTQA3qn34GWLm1DVQ-trMI",
  authDomain: "mymart-fcca0.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://mymart-fcca0.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "mymart-fccb0",
  storageBucket: "mymart-fccb0.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1088382632990",
  appId: "1:1088382632990:web:49c0c48346f5ffb46e5a0f",
  measurementId: "G-ZFMB1PQLVN",
};
```

Comment: Please describe how you get this error. and also include your relevant code. You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am unsure but can you try with firebase@5.5.7 and @firebase-tools@7.12.0. angularfire2 is a little old and may have caused conflict with newer versions

Comment: @frunkad is that a different library?

Comment: Yup, it was ported from angularfire2 to @angular/fire